# return Partial() throws The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type error

Tags: c#, partial-views, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.2 in my web project.

I have a partial view named `_UserPartial` which has a model declared like `@model UserViewModel`

From my Razor Page Handler, though I'm passing the correct model type to my partial view, I'm getting this strange behavior with

```cs
return Partial("_UserPartial", UserDetail);
```

above piece of code throws

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type
>   'Web.Models.UserViewModel', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'Web.Areas.Master.Pages.UserModel'.

where `UserModel` is the `PageModel` of my page containing my page handler.

but this works fine with below implementation

```cs
return new PartialViewResult
{
     ViewName = "_UserPartial",
     ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<UserViewModel>(ViewData, UserDetail)
};
```

> I believe The Partial helper method was added to the PageModel class in ASP.NET
>   Core 2.2

I tried removing the `@model UserViewModel` from `_UserPartial` and tried

```cs
return Partial("_UserPartial");
```

and surprisingly this works. But I need to pass a model.

My Page and Partial is inside a Area named Master. Here is the screen print.
[image: Folder Structure]

I'm getting this error because of having page inside Area and Models folder outside Area?

My `_UserPartial.cshtml` Partial View:

```
@model Web.Models.UserViewModel

<div class="modal fade p-0 d-print-none" role="dialog" aria-label="User Detail" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
     id="userEditModal">
...
```

My `User.cshtml` Page:

```
@page "{handler?}"
@model UserModel

@section pagestyles{
...
```

My `User.cshtml.cs`

```cs
namespace Web.Areas.Master.Pages
{
    public class UserModel : PageModel
    {
          public UserViewModel UserDetail { get; set; }
...
```

And finally my `PageHandler`,

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetUserById(
            [FromQuery] Guid id,
            CancellationToken ct)
{
    var user = await _userBusiness.GetUserByIdAsync(id, ct);
    UserDetail = _mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(user);

    return Partial("_UserPartial", UserDetail);

    //return new PartialViewResult
    //{
    //    ViewName = "_UserPartial",
    //    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<UserViewModel>(ViewData, UserDetail)
    //};
}
```

Any clue on where I'm going wrong? Please assist.

Comment: No there is no `return PartialView()` in Razor Pages

Comment: The error message makes it pretty clear that the model specified **in the partial** is **not** the same as the one passed in. And your code clearly shows this.

Comment: @ErikPhilips `UserDetail` is a property in my `User` RazorPage of type `UserViewModel` and that's what I have declared in my `_UserPartial`. I have updated the code and fixed the typo in commented code.

Comment: looks like this is an open issue in github and targeted for asp.net core 3.0 - https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10438